# How to insert data into mysql using loop back

Tags: scripts, python, mysql

I'm done loopback and mysql connection, But i don't know how to insert the data in to tables. Can anyone help me?

**DB connection**

```
"mysqlds": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3306,
    "url": "",
    "database": "demo",
    "password": "root",
    "name": "mysqlds",
    "user": "root",
    "connector": "mysql"
  }
```

Then how to proceed insert data into the corresponding  table?

Comment: Are you asking about the syntax of an `insert … values … into table` SQL statement?

Comment: I know mysql syntax. But i don't know how to implement into loopback for api.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and show how you connect to the DB and what problems you got? Do you use the command line client? Or Perl, Python, C, …? Inserting data into a DB is independent of the connection method and loopback is just another IP address to connect to.

Comment: Loopback is one of nodejs frameworks, and judging from the posted code this is a typical syntax( [see documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Connecting-to-MySQL.html) ).  This makes more programming specific , hence off-topic

Comment: I did well connection, but I don't know how to send data webpage to database using loopback....